# API Call works for IPv4 Address (127.0.0.1) but get a "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3001" when using localhost

Tags: express, next.js, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4

So I have a very simple API call using fetch on my frontend to `http://localhost:3001/test` that gives me an error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3001`

However, when I call that API directly (enter the api uri directly into my browser), it works just fine. Also when I change localhost to `http://127.0.0.1:3001/test` on my frontend fetch call, that works too.

This seems like it's gotta be a network error since ::1 and 127.0.0.1 resolve to the same address but one is IPv4 and the other is IPv6 right? Anyone have any thoughts on why this could be?

frontend fetch (BACKEND_URL = http://localhost:3001):

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/explore`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
      Origin: BASE_URL,
    },
  });

  ...
}
```

Backend Server listening on port 3001 (PORT = 3001):

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Stack: NextJS frontend, ExpressJS backend, MongoDB Atlas DB, NextAuth for auth

Comment: Do you have anything in your local hosts file that points `localhost` to `::1`? This sounds more like a network-related issue, rather than a coding one.

Comment: @juliomalves yeah doesn't seem like a coding one – what do you mean by local hosts file? if localhost is pointed to ::1 somewhere instead of 127.0.0.1 is that necessarily incorrect? Or does it only not work because express only listens on IPv4 addresses? Because those should be equivalent addresses correct?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things can be the issue:

1. You need to enclose the IPv6 address between brackets, like http://[::1]:3001/test
2. The service is only listening on the IPv4 address and not on the IPv6 address. Depending on the server you may need to configure the listening address differently

Your post doesn’t contain enough information to go into more detail. Please edit your post to include the actual code, service and configuration so we can help you further.

Comment: thanks, added the code. Configuration is NextJS frontend running on port 3000 and an ExpressJS backend running on port 3001. The actual fetch url is "http://localhost:3001/explore" but NextJS seems to be translating that to "http://::1:3001/explore" based on the error I was getting

Answer (score 0):

When you use "localhost" in the backend URL, that is by default going to be resolved to the IPv6 address `::1`. However, looking at the backend server code, that backend is listening on `0.0.0.0` which is IPv4.

You need to make that backend listen on IPv6:

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, '::', () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers pointed to the issue, you server is only listening to IpV4 ip but your "localhost" is translated into IpV6

One way to check your mappings in Mac/Linux is checking the content of /etc/hosts, you will something like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

The last ip (::1) is the IPv6 format for localhost.
A quick hack is to comment the IPv6 from your hosts file and try if that fix the issue (simply add # at the beginning of that line):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1             localhost
```

If this fix the issue and you still need to use IPv6 then you have to review the configuration of your server (but sometimes we don't have control on how our servers are configured so this would do the trick)